# Django GET or POST data will NOT bind to form

Tags: django, django-forms

My form data will NOT bind no matter what I do.  As you can see in my code, I have set up dynamic 'mutlipleChoice' fields (aka drop down menus).  I won't go into why but the **must** be dynamically generated.  My (truncated) forms.Form is (truncated b/c of all the menu choice definitions):

```
class BatchMap (forms.Form):

    column_labels = forms.CharField(initial='True', widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):               
        SKIP = ''
        OPTIONAL_BATCH_ID = 'investor_batch_id'  
        VTYPE = 'type'
        #!!truncated definitions here!!
        ZIP = 'zip*'

        MENU_CHOICES = (        
        (SKIP, '(skip column)'),
        (VTYPE, '*Valuation Type'),          
        #!!truncated definitions here!!
        (ZIP, '*Zip Code'), 
        )

        empty_cols = kwargs.pop('empty_cols')
        rows = kwargs.pop('rows')

        super(BatchMap, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for col_count, cell_val in enumerate(rows, empty_cols):
            self.fields[col_count] = forms.ChoiceField(
                                            choices=MENU_CHOICES,                                            
                                            label=cell_val, 
                                            required=False,
                                            )                                            

    def clean(self):
        data = super(BatchMap, self).clean()
        print data
        if 'VTYPE' not in data.itervalues():
            raise forms.ValidationError("You MUST specify a type")
        return data
```

My View as follows (I have also truncated code to try and keep things more focused) :

```
def data_parse(request):
    xl_file_name = request.session['temp_file_name']
    temp_filepath = join(TEMP_PATH, xl_file_name)
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(temp_filepath)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'sheet radio' in request.GET:        
            selected_sheet_index = int(request.GET['sheet radio'])             
            chosen_sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(selected_sheet_index)
            chosen_sheet_name = chosen_sheet.name
            empty_rows = 0
            empty_cols = 0
            empty_error = ''
            #!!TRUNCATED CODE THAT HAS BEEN TESTED!!       

            request.session['header'] = row_header
            request.session['start_cols'] = empty_cols
            request.session.modified = True           
            form = BatchMap(rows=row_header, empty_cols=empty_cols)             
            return render (request, 'colmap.html', {'form':form})                                       

        elif 'column_labels' in request.GET:                    
            row_header = request.session['header']
            empty_cols = request.session['start_cols'] 
            form = BatchMap(request.GET, rows=row_header, empty_cols=empty_cols) 
       ---> #form = BatchMap(request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                parse_map = form.cleaned_data                
                return HttpResponse('valid')
```

Finally, my template:

```
    <html>
<h3>(an '*' indicates a required column assignment)</h3>
{% if form.errors %}
<p style="color: red;">
    Please correct the following: {{ form.errors }} below
</p>
{% endif %}
<form action="" method="GET">
    {{form.as_ul}}
<input type="submit" value="Submit Valuations">
</form>
</html>
```

So whats happening?  Well, you can see in my form clean() I have marked off a '--->' by an oddly print statement.  I have done that to test what is output.  And what i get is:

Apparently I don't have enough 'rep' to post an image, which really ruins the effect, but my local test environment server (the python command line) outputs this:

...development server at http;//127.0.0.1:8000/...

{0: u'', 1: u'', 2: u'', 3: u'', 4: u'', 5: u''}
[09/Mar/2014 03:08:54] "GET /bulkincep/column_man/?0=due_date&1=lock_box_code&2=city*&3 
=&4=&5=zip*&column_labels=True HTTP/1.1"

The form data is showing up as GET data in the URL (I've also tried switching everything to POST, FYI), but will not bind to my form.  I always get an **empty dictionary**.
I've tried checking for it BEFORE validation and AFTER validation.  Data from the drop down menus is nowhere to be found!
Where the '--->' mark is in my view is where I tried passing the GET data to my form WITHOUT any of the necessary arguments (and modified the form accordingly, of course) to see if it would bind.  Nothing.

I even tried accessing data from the form BEFORE it is cleaned by changing my view to:

```
    elif 'column_labels' in request.GET:                    
        row_header = request.session['header']
        empty_cols = request.session['start_cols'] 
        form = BatchMap(request.GET, rows=row_header, empty_cols=empty_cols)
   ---> if form[0]=='due_date':
            return HttpResponse('SUCCESS!')
```

I'm sorry this is so long, but I've spent over a dozen hours tweaking my code and the dictionary is ALWAYS empty.  The only thing that gets passed is my hidden input of "column_labels".  It has to be something with my dynamically generated fields.  But what?

PS -- excuse/ignore some of the initial indent mistakes on my code.  This is my first post and I was having trouble getting the first line of the code blocks to indent (I guess it would actually be UN-indented) properly

Comment: I don't really understand what most of this code is doing, but you need to return the cleaned data from the `clean` method.

Comment: Absolutely you do.  I edited my question appropriately.  I have always had the 'return data' line in my code, just edited it out by mistake while removing a bunch of my repetitive error checking code before posting here.  Trying to make the question easier to digest.

Comment: To add context to what this code does: It allows a user to upload a spreadsheet of data.  Once the user does that, the program returns the first row of data from the spreadsheet, and displays _each_ column from this row as a field on the 'BatchMap' form.  Using these fields, the user selects from drop down menues (the ChoiceField) to specify which columns in his spreadsheet represent: address, city, state, etc etc.

Comment: OK, thanks. Is that the actual form definition? I notice there are some syntax errors (eg missing `for`), so you havent't simply copied and pasted. In particular, is the signature of `__init__` correct?

Comment: Shoot!  I don't know what happened to the 'for' in the for loop.  I must've erased it when trying to get my indenting correct. It is in fact in my code.                                                  This is the actual form definition with the following exception:    Where is says !!truncated...!!  I've removed several lines of constant definition, tuple choices, and non-relevant validation logic                                                                        I double checked the init signature and super call.  Both are verbatim.  Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My partner figured out the answer to this question.

In my form I had

```
for col_count, cell_val in enumerate(rows, empty_cols):
    self.fields[col_count] = forms.ChoiceField
```

The problem with this is it was generating a field name that was simply a number.  As per 
Jacob Kaplan

http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

this must not just be CONVENTION, but the actual way it needs to be for Django to recognize these dynamically generated fields in order for Django to bind the POST or GET data to the form.  I didn't experiment with other names, I simply stuck with JKM and went with:

```
    for col_count, cell_val in enumerate(rows, empty_cols):
        self.fields['custom_%s' % col_count] = forms.ChoiceField
```

and was too happy that it worked to look back.  Thanks for the suggestions Dan Roseman.